# Recommendation request for stereoscopy workflow

Tags: final-cut-pro-x, 3d, workflow

I occasionally do video editing in spare time. I've made a few 3D videos, and I seek to improve my workflow. I use Final Cut (I hope to get FCPX answers, but open to others so that it'd be useful to folks using other NLEs, and I may adapt that for FCPX as well), and here's roughly my existing workflow:

1. **Shooting**: I shoot with 2 Canon EOS R7, set in video mode (it has separate modes for stills and motion), with shutter port connected using a 2.5mm cable (I've set shutter signal to "start/stop recording" under video mode). Although this simpifies synchronizing, it still have some delays.
2. **Pre-Processing**: Video assets are imported into multi-cam timeline. Assets are

   1. time-aligned (because I cable-synced 2 cameras, L/R videos usually ends simultaneously)
   2. rotated and shifted to align 2 eyes' image.
3. Here's the part that's most effort consuming: I have to edit 2 versions: one with only 1 eye, and another with both eyes. And when I color-grade 1 eye, I'll have to copy the color-grading effects one-by-one to the other eye, since when I switch side on the multi-cam clip, the corresponding color-grading effect is also switched away.
4. **Render & Release**: The platform I use (due to national Internet censorship, I don't use Youtube) allows me to post multiple videos in a single entry. I send a 4K version, and a 1080p SBS version to Compressor to encode into MP4 for upload.

The 3rd point is where my pain is. I suppose I could make a Motion "effect" to help switching eye when grading color; there's the stereoscopy role in the "info" panel of selected clips/assets, but I don't know how they're to be used.

Any and all recommendations and suggestions are appreciated.